# .net application hangs in iis7.0 at peak time randomly

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

we have our own webserver in that internal applications are hosted in that one of the application will be used at peak time by around 300 employees

this application get hangs some times in peak time

server details as follows:
windows server 2008 standard
IIS 7.0
.net framework 4.0
sql server 2005

I have created one application pool for 2 .net internal applications in same configuration as specified above. the other application will not get hangs in peak time and running smooth with similar number of users.

I have one doubt is some one forcefully stopping the application to run slow and get hangs .

Please let us know what will be the exact solution as i am getting this issue since 2 years and i googled and done changes in queries, IIS settings and code standards. but still the same problem persists making my life disaster.

some times i get errors as
1. network tcp_errors server may busy or server is down
2. in event logs login failure for sa
3. some times CPU usage will be 100% at peak time

Comment: Did you monitor memory leaks ?

Comment: may i know how to monitor memory leaks

Comment: I'll suggest to use https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/. There is 5 day trial. Also notice that the hang-up may occur when GC is starting to garbage leaked memory.

Comment: all applications in my remote server are working fine except one application which i specified above

Comment: Network Error (tcp_error) 

A communication error occurred: ""
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.this error i getting for my .net application other application are working with same application pool

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are a lot of different reasons why something like this might happen. I spent a month or so chasing something similar down on our system. It's almost certainly a user-level coding error of some sort, whether in your own code, or in the code of one or more of the libraries that you're using. But beyond that, tracking it down specifically can be a real pain, and you'll likely need to use one or more tools to help you.

Beyond the JetBrains "dotmemory" tool that someone has already suggested, if you've got access to the server, you may want to install Visual Studio, and debug the problem from within Visual Studio. Hook it up to the IIS process, wait until the problem manifests itself, and then hit "Debug", and see what's going on. If you don't have the ability to install Visual Studio onto the machine, you can also debug remotely - see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38132/Remote-IIS-Debugging-Debug-your-ASP-NET-Applicatio and elsewhere.

Comment: i have access to the server and i will install vs2010 today then may i know how to debug by using visual studio 2010 and may i know how debug option will fire in my code when any error occures from user side